# Calculate difference between first login and last logout with merging with other table - [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get difference in hours between login and logout of the user.

```
SELECT t_logins.log_id,
t_logins.log_date,
t_logins.log_time, t_logouts.log_time,
 (DATE_PART('hour', t_logouts.log_time - t_logins.log_time) * 60 +
     DATE_PART('minute', t_logouts.log_time - t_logins.log_time)) / 60 as log_delta
FROM t_logins, t_logouts
ORDER BY t_logins.log_date DESC, t_logouts.log_date DESC
```

It works fine, but when I'm trying to merge Users table (t_users), it returns junk data. How to merge correctly? OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN in different combination do not help.

```
SELECT t_logins.log_id,
t_users.first_name || ' ' || t_users.last_name,
t_logins.log_date,
t_logins.log_time, t_logouts.log_time,
 (DATE_PART('hour', t_logouts.log_time - t_logins.log_time) * 60 +
     DATE_PART('minute', t_logouts.log_time - t_logins.log_time)) / 60 as log_delta
FROM t_logins
LEFT JOIN t_logouts
    ON t_logouts.log_date = t_logins.log_date
LEFT JOIN t_users
    ON t_users.user_id = t_logins.user_id
ORDER BY t_logins.log_date DESC, t_logouts.log_date DESC
```

Returns:

```
17  "Alex Smith"    "2020-07-17"    "13:55:00"  "10:30:00"  -3.4166666666666665
17  "Alex Smith"    "2020-07-17"    "13:55:00"  "23:02:00"  9.116666666666667
17  "Alex Smith"    "2020-07-17"    "13:55:00"  "14:00:00"  0.08333333333333333
```

But table contains only one login and logout point for every user every day (first login and last logout). Difference is always zero or positive. So this is result of incorrect merging.

I've tried to give more strict rule on merging, but it throws error (yes, obviously, but I don't know how to merge it correctly anyway)

How to get only one answer for a user on every day?

Comment: Don't mix implicit joins (`from t_logins, t_logouts`)  with explicit JOIN operator

Comment: Sample data and desired results might make it possible to understand your question.  A clear explanation would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete answer provide sample data for each table, as text - **no images**. However your query(join version) does have a obvious major issue. The condition:

```
select ...
  FROM t_logins
  LEFT JOIN t_logouts
    ON t_logouts.log_date = t_logins.log_date
  ...
```

This joins every t_logouts with every t_logins for a given date, without regard to whether it the same user or not. It also says give me the t_logins for any date that does not have a t_logouts for that date. What happens then? Leaving t he question of missing t_logouts aside, you (at a minimum) need to insure that the login user corresponds to the logout user. So:

```
select ... 
  FROM t_logins
  LEFT JOIN t_logouts
    ON (    t_logouts.log_date = t_logins.log_date
        and t_logouts.user_id  = t_logins.user_id
       ) 
  ...
```

Actually, your first query with "FROM t_logins, t_logouts" without a WHERE actually joins does a cross join of every row in t_logins joined to every row t_logouts.

Comment: I've changed to inner in case of absence of login or logout. it works great! thank you very much! God bless you!

`INNER JOIN t_logouts
ON ( t_logouts.log_date = t_logins.log_date AND t_logouts.user_id  = t_logins.user_id )`